# Trying to Query an object in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    print("woot")
                }
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            //reload the table view

            query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.NetworkElseCache
        }

    }
```

For some reason, the line:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

is giving me the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> void to expected argument type 'PFQueryArrayResultBlock?'

I have no idea how to fix the error.

Thanks!

Comment: First param of the block should be `objects: [PFObject]?`

Answer (score 0):

The result block should be like the following:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
                print("woot")
            }
        }

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        print("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        //reload the table view

        query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.NetworkElseCache
    }
}
```

See [Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries) on querying.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'AnyObject' to 'PFObject' in the first line.  Parse v1.9.0 changed the PFObject fetch functions to be compatible with iOS 9 / Swift 2 (https://parse.com/docs/downloads).

You'll then not have to cast 'as? [PFObject]' in line 4.

Answer (score 0):

Parse no longer uses AnyObject for Swift 2.0. So for your code change:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

to

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

and since you no longer need to cast objects as a PFObject you can shorten it to:

```
if error == nil {
         for object in objects! {
                print("woot")
         }
    } else {...
```

Hope this helped!